# how to make searchResultsTableView use custom cell instead of default cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `uisearchbar` that does a search successfully.  The problem is that the `searchResultsTableView` doesn't show the results because it is using a regular `UITableViewCell` instead of my custom cell.  I have set this custom cell in storyboards and connected the outlets to make sure everything is working properly.

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InviteCell";

    InviteTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[InviteTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyUser *person = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {

        person = [self.filteredContactArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        //This works and shows
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"testing if using default cell";

    }
    else
    {
        person = [self.inviteContactsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }




    //InviteTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    person = [self.inviteContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //these do not work and do not show in the results view
    cell.nameLabel.text = person.fullName;
    cell.emailLabel.text = person.email;

    return cell;

}
```

This is what the results view looks like:

[image]

Comment: How is this question different from the question I already answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920473/ios-search-bar-not-showing-results/23922214#23922214 ?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way for a prototype cell created in a storyboard to be registered in the `searchResultsTableView`.

A workaround is to put the cell into a separate xib file and register it for both the `self.tableView` and the `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` using `-[UITableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]`.

For further information about this method see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943) of `UITableView`.